# Spring MVC / Hibernate / Eclipse - Why Automatically Generated Model Files?

Tags: eclipse

I have a Spring MVC based Java project.  This project uses hibernate for the ORM.  I am also using Eclipse Kepler as an IDE.  I have a question about the Model portion of my project.  All of the .java files that I have that are the Model files have an equivalent named file that ends in an underscore.  These equivalent files ending in the underscore were automatically generated "I think by the IDE".  I have no idea why these files got generated and what their purpose is.  Can someone shed some light on this and point me in the right direction?  I feel this is either an incorrect IDE setting that is causing them to get generated or is being generated due to some configuration setting that I have within my project.

For instance I have a User.java and a User_.java file.  I wrote the User.java but not the User_.java.  The User_.java was generated automatically.  The code for each of these files is below, the first block is the User_.java that was generated automatically.

```
package com.bah.iaat.model.data;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="Dali", date="2014-04-03T23:00:06.698-0400")
@StaticMetamodel(AnalyticAgenda.class)
public class AnalyticAgenda_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<AnalyticAgenda, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<AnalyticAgenda, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<AnalyticAgenda, String> desc;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<AnalyticAgenda, Integer> userGroupId;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<AnalyticAgenda, String> flag;
}
```

The next block of code is the code that I wrote:

```
package com.bah.iaat.model.data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "SelectAllUsers",query = "Select u from User u"),
@NamedQuery(name = "SelectUserByName",query = "Select u from User u where u.name =:uName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "findUserByIdentifier",query = "Select u from User u where u.name =:pId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "findUserIdByName",query = "select u.id from User u where u.name =:pName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "findUserByName",query = "select u from User u where u.name =:pName")})
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS") 
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME", unique=true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="LAST_LOGIN")
    private Date lastLogin;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_GROUP_ID" )  
    private UserGroup userGroup;

    public User() {}  

    public User(String name, UserGroup userGroup, Date lastLogin){
        this.name = name;       
        this.userGroup = userGroup;     
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes constitute the metamodel of your persistence context. They are used when you use the JPA2 Criteria API, in order to create type-safe queries, based on identifiers instead of Strings. For example:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> from = query.from(Person.class);
query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(person.get(Person_.name), "Doe"));
```

Using `Person_.name` instead of `"name"` guarantees that you're using a field that exists, and makes sure you'll get a compilation error instead of a runtime error if you rename the field `name` to `lastName`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this makes sense.  Sounds like something I want to use and keep enabled.